# Как записать значение в таблицу выбранное в <select>? PHP, MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Не работала форма потому что вчера у меня комп зафризил и БД приняла ислам, когда создавал ее заново пропустил один столбец. В общем этот вопрос снят, но остается другой: как из выпадающего списка, когда выбрал значение, занести его в БД?

```html
<option value="0" class="colortext">Выберите тип недвижимости</option>
            <?
            $cat_id = $_GET['cat_id'];
            $res = mysql_query('select `cat_id`, `name` from `categories`');
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
                ?>
                <option value="<?= $row['cat_id'] ?>"><?= $row['name'] ?></option>
            <? } ?>
        </select><br/> 
  
$cat_id = $_GET['cat_id'];

$rest = get_rest($id);
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO realestate(cat_id)
VALUES ('$cat_id')");
```

Comment: Что значит "не добавляются". приведите код, который это пытается делать и обязательно расставьте в коде проверку на ошибки выполнения SQL и вывод этих ошибок

Comment: да я пост первый на сайт раз добавляю, не сразу понял как правильно вставить код

Comment: А теперь посмотрите первый же пример по использованию функции mysql_query в ее описании http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php  Там написано, что после mysql_query надо проверить на ошибки и вывести их ... и это действительно надо. отлаживать черные ящики нереально. еще может помочь печать текста запроса после его сборки и попытка его выполнить в ручную в консоли mysql

Comment: расширение mysql_query устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и удалено в PHP 7.0.0. Используйте вместо него MySQLi или PDO_MySQL.

Comment: Наугад выстрелю - точку с запятой в конце запроса не поставили.

Comment: Не первый пример к mysql_query смотрите, а второй. 


@Morlok Точка с запятой необязательна в mysql_query

Comment: Сделал по второму примеру, выдает: Неверный запрос: Query was empty

Comment: не пойму, он сам должен добавиться в базу? Где сабмит на отправку селекта?-точнее формы с селектом? Его нет, а чего вы ожидаете, она сама должна создаться? Или используйте `ajax`.

Answer (score -1):

```
  <select name="cat_id" class="colortext">
              <option value="0" class="colortext">Выберите тип недвижимости</option>
              <?
              $cat_id = $_GET['cat_id'];
              $res = mysql_query('select `cat_id`, `name` from `categories`');
              while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
                  ?>
                  <option name="<?= $row['cat_id'] ?>" value="<?= $row['cat_id'] ?>"><?= $row['name'] ?></option>
              <? } ?>
          </select><br/>
```